# Attempting to read from GPIO23 but it only reads 0

Tags: pi-3, pigpio

I am trying to follow this [guide](https://blog.bschwind.com/2016/05/29/sending-infrared-commands-from-a-raspberry-pi-without-lirc/) on making an ir receiver/blaster.  Currently I am trying to work on the receiver end of things but the pin reads 0 at the beginning instead of 1 like the guide says.

Here is the python script I am running to test the receiver.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import math
import os
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

# This is for revision 1 of the Raspberry Pi, Model B
# This pin is also referred to as GPIO23
INPUT_WIRE = 16

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(INPUT_WIRE, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

while True:
    value = 1
    # Loop until we read a 0
    while value:
        value = GPIO.input(INPUT_WIRE)
        print value      

    # Grab the start time of the command
    startTime = datetime.now()

    # Used to buffer the command pulses
    command = []

    # The end of the "command" happens when we read more than
    # a certain number of 1s (1 is off for my IR receiver)
    numOnes = 0

    # Used to keep track of transitions from 1 to 0
    previousVal = 0

    while True:

        if value != previousVal:
            # The value has changed, so calculate the length of this run
            now = datetime.now()
            pulseLength = now - startTime
            startTime = now

            command.append((previousVal, pulseLength.microseconds))

        if value:
            numOnes = numOnes + 1
        else:
            numOnes = 0

        # 10000 is arbitrary, adjust as necessary
        if numOnes > 10000:
            break

        previousVal = value
        value = GPIO.input(INPUT_WIRE)

print "----------Start----------"
for (val, pulse) in command:
    print val, pulse
print "-----------End-----------\n"

print "Size of array is " + str(len(command))
```

This is my wiring setup.
[image]

Comment: It looks like the formatting is incorrect in your python code.  Add some indenting tabs after the "if value != previousVal:"  statement.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy paste error the tabs didn't seem to indent, they are indented properly in the code I'm running.  My issue is that the python code from the guide says the IR receiver should be emitting 1 until it reads a signal but it is immediately emitting 0.

Comment: You set the `pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN`, if you are expecting an initial value of 1, try `GPIO.PUD_UP`.